# Azure Service Fabric - different publish settings for different environments

Tags: visual-studio, azure-service-fabric

This seems like an easy question, but I still haven't found an answer to it, despite having spent a lot of time reading the documentation and related articles on the internet. I have a SF application with several services that I wish to be able to package (from Visual Studio) for different environments: dev, test, prod. These environments require different settings, for example the user the application will run as, the connection string to the database, etc. I have managed to change the environment variables on a particular cluster with Start-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade command, but this way I can't set everything I need, and anyway I'd prefer to have all the configuration I need in the application package. What should I do? In the case it matters, I use Windows standalone clusters (except in dev environment, which is a local development cluster).

Answer (score 4):

#### Service level

In your ServiceManifest.xml located under `{YourService}\PackageRoot\ServiceManifest.xml`.

You'll have an entry `CodePackage` add the tag `EnvironmentVariables` underneat it with the EnvironmentVariables you want to use with an empty value.

```
<CodePackage Name="Code" Version="1.0.0">
    <EntryPoint>
        <!--...-->
    </EntryPoint>
    <EnvironmentVariables>
        <EnvironmentVariable Name="Connectionstring" Value=""/>
    </EnvironmentVariables>
</CodePackage>
```

To access it in your code you can use

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Connectionstring", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

#### Application level

In your `ApplicationManifest.xml`located under `{YourApplication}\ApplicationPackageRoot\ApplicationManifest.xml`

There is a section `<Parameters>` add a parameter for every value you want to set at deploy time.

```
<Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="Connectionstring" DefaultValue="{your connectionstring}" />
</Parameters>
```

In the same file (application manifest) there is `ServiceManifestImport` you need to extend this with `EnvironmentOverrides` for every service.

```
<ServiceManifestImport>
    <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="MyServicePkg" ServiceManifestVersion="1.0.0" />
    <ConfigOverrides />
    <EnvironmentOverrides CodePackageRef="code">
      <EnvironmentVariable Name="Connectionstring" Value="[Connectionstring]" />
    </EnvironmentOverrides>
</ServiceManifestImport>
```

The value in the square brackets, is a value thats replaced by the parameter defined in `<Parameters>` tag.

#### Environment specific configs

Under the `{YourApplication}\ApplicationParameters` folder. Create a file for every environment. Example `Test.xml` and specify a parameter with the value for the environment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Application xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="fabric:/{YourApplication}" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric">
  <Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="Connectionstring" Value="{Your test connection string}" />
  </Parameters>
</Application>
```

After creating the Settings file, you need to create a publish profile that uses this settings file. Uner `{YourApplication}\PublishProfiles\` create a file for the environment. Example `Test.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PublishProfile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2015/05/fabrictools">
  <ClusterConnectionParameters ConnectionEndpoint="{YourEndpoint}" />
  <!--Reference the settings file-->
  <ApplicationParameterFile Path="..\ApplicationParameters\Test.xml" />
  <UpgradeDeployment Mode="UnmonitoredAuto" Enabled="true">
  
    <!--Specify additonal upgrade parameters here--> 
    <Parameters />
  </UpgradeDeployment>
</PublishProfile>
```

After you've done this, Its just a matter of deploying the application with the correct publish profile.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Will this approach also work in cases where other settings (besides the environment variables) have to be changed. Like RunAs user for the application, which is different between environments. Or having HTTP port for web apps on DEV and certificate protected HTTPS for TEST/PROD environments?

Comment: You can use [resource overrides](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-service-manifest-resources#overriding-endpoints-in-servicemanifestxml) to control the ports. Haven't experimented with RunAs policies. But my guess the same syntax should work.

Comment: I wonder how do PackageRoot\Config\Settings.xml files that exist for every service integrate in the above scenario? What's their purpose, what additional benefit do they bring?

Comment: From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-and-service-manifests: 
Config package is the contents of the Config directory under PackageRoot that contains an independently-updateable and versioned set of custom configuration settings for your service.

Comment: There's an API to access the config file: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.configurationpackage?view=azure-dotnet - Main benefit is that they are versioned and following rolling upgrade policies in Service Fabric.